# Problems with lazy loading EF MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with some related entities in EF.

This is my Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AtpID { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string AtpName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ArticleNo { get; set; }
    public string SupplierNo { get; set; }
    public string AtpPrice { get; set; }
    public string AtpStock { get; set; }
    public string AtpDeliveryDays { get; set; }
    public bool FitsAllCars { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductReference> ProductReferences { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This is the ProductDetails class:

```
public class ProductDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ProductDetailTypeId { get; set; } 
    public int ProductDetailKeyId { get; set; }       
    public string AtpTextKey { get; set; }
    public string AtpTextValue { get; set; }
    public string TextKey { get; set; }
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is that the ProductDetails is not loading for the products, as you can see in the attached screenshot, it gives me an error:

[image]

the ProductReferences is loaded correctly, only with the ProductDetails I have this problem. 
Can you help me in this problem? I didn't know what can cause this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: please use Include when you select

Comment: Where is your Query ?

Comment: Are you getting an exception or something when you try to access the related collection?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an include issue since it seems you are using lazy loading, otherwise you wouldn't have the ProductReferences. Can you show the code of the query? What is the exact exception you are getting when trying to see the contents of the ProductDetails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use Include when you select :

```
 _context.Product.Include('ProductDetails').ToList()
```

if you want to enable lazy loading then please check 
   this is set in DBContext class if it is false it will not load . then you need to use Eager Loading as mentioned in my answer

```
  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: I tried this way, and it is strange because I get this error: Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'OnlineCarStore.DAL.Product' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ProductDetail'.. Altought I have the navigation property in the Product class

Comment: I tried with  ProductDetail and is not working var productList =  db.Product.Include("ProductDetail");

Comment: using the include overload that accepts a Func instead of a string is even better for many reasons including avoiding those kind of errors.

Comment: var productList = db.Product.Include("ProductDetails"); please look the name of the property in your Product class is ProductDetails not ProductDetail .

Comment: it shouldn't matter: can't tell for sure because @Orsi still did not show the exception, but since he has DynamicProxies, lazy loading seems to be on, so no need of eager loading except performance

Comment: I resolved the problem after all. The problem was that I had two fields in my ProductDetails class, but in the db was already deleted. But only when I tried the Include method, then I received some messages with the missing fields. Thanks you guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

Include ProductDetails with something like this:

```
var products = await _ctx.Products
                .Include(p => p.ProductDetails)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have encountered exception caused by circular reference. Please note that Product contains references to ProductDetails and ProductDetails in turn contains reference to Product. When you try to serialize this aggregate(object graph) circular references exception is thrown.

Best approach would be to use DTOs to transfer only the data that you want to consume in specific view. The DTOs should have just simple properties so it won't create a circular reference error.